# Holding left mouse button in Minecraft Java edition on Windows

Tags: mouseevent, minecraft, lwjgl, glfw, sendmessage

I am trying to simulate user input in Minecraft Java Edition on Windows running in background. Specifically, I want to simulate holding left mouse button.

In order to simplify it, I set `rawMouseInput:false` in `options.txt`.

For mouse input the issue is that after receiving `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` Minecraft behaves as if `WM_LBUTTONUP` immediately followed although I can see in the debugger that it is not the case. As a result actions like mining a block start but are immediately interrupted.

Now I did some investigation, and it seems that Minecraft is using LWJGL 3 Java library, which in turn uses GLFW C library to handle user input.

I cloned latest GLFW and built a simple `boing` example. However, I can not reproduce the same issue with that example: `boing` appears to correctly treat `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` as the beginning of the action, and does not stop the action until I send `WM_LBUTTONUP`.

Is there something special Minecraft does for input that causes such behavior?

How do I simulate holding left mouse button in Minecraft running in background?

Comment: Please make your question clearer

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you've overthought this a bit too much.
Java has a built-in keyboard and mouse simulator, which, as far as I've seen, works fine.

```
java.awt.Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.mousePress(MouseEvent.<your_button_here>);
---<wait however long you want>---
robot.mouseRelease(MouseEvent.<your_button_here>);
```

Sorry if this appears off-topic, but it does avoid a whole host of problems...

Comment: This does not work for apps running in background.

Comment: That's why I said it seemed off-topic.
However, as I also said, if the app isn't running in the bg, it saves a lot of effort.